# Extracting a value from a serializearray() before sending it in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to extract a value from a form and concatinate it with a fixed string and serialize it again before sending it in ajax

```
e.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();
var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();

$.each(other_data,function(key,input){
    data.append(input.name,input.value);
});

//I want to extract one data and concatenate with a string and serialize it again before sending it via ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //$(".cvf_uploaded_files").html('');                                                
        //bootbox.alert('<br /><p class = "bg-success">uploaded successfully.</p>');
    }
});
```

thanks for help

Comment: How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: Do that in the `.each` loop Test for the field you want to modify and do it inside the `.each` loop

Comment: The question is why? From the options you've passed to `$.ajax` it looks like you're rtying to send files, and `serializeArray` does not include binary data, but if you know the key (elements name), it's trivial to find the value and concatenate it with something.

Comment: I want to pass a files after doing this . I did this for testing but it doesn't extract the values  var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
     
    $.each(other_data,function(key,input){
    data.append(input.name,input.value);
    alert (data[input.name]);
    });